# cannot run 'symfony' command on windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, pear, symfony-3.2

I came from frontend stack so I can misanderstand something when I'm learning symfony3.

I downloaded Symfony according to documentation with:

```
php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

To make php command available i added some values to the enviroment PATH variable (according to this tutorial: https://seiler.it/installing-symfony-framework-into-xampp-for-windows/ - step 2.3) like this:

> c:\xampp\mysql\bin;c:\xampp\php;c:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\php\symfony

As you see I'm using xampp for PHP development. I added that last, because i copied that downloaded symfony file to c:\xampp\php\symfony directory.

OK, now if i want to use symfony command, like

```
symfony new project
```

I need to go to directory where there is that symfony file and add 'php' before, like

```
php symfony new project
```

Because simple 'symfony new project' doesn't work (error msg tells about that command isn't known by Windows). How can i fix it?

In frontend there is something like npm (node package manager) with which you can install library/tool locally in directory or globally (to run it in terminal from any place on the computer). Is there is any equivalent in PHP development? I tried to install this by pear (from mentioned tutorial in step 7), but it installed me symfony 1.x version (and error of running that command was that there is no task like 'new') and i want to learn 3, not 1.

I tried to get composer, but i don't see where can i install there symfony globally.

So, how to run symfony globally? What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

## [From this doc:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications)

> In Windows, move the symfony file to a directory that's included in the PATH environment variable to create the global command or move it to any other directory convenient for you

## idea

Install and use [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win). Gives you more futures then the windows CLI.

## Performance

To run a ten times more fast environment for Symfony i prefer a Linux OS.